# how to run multiple java servers on the same machine on the same port 443

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have EC2 instance which running multiple java servers, each server use local port 1234, and I have Elastic IP for each java server, and I use iptables to resirect traffic on EIP:443 to EIP:1234 so I need to reserve EIPs for all java servers and I need to open the port 1234 on firewalls from outside to make the application reachable

I am searching for an optimal solution to reduce number of reserved IPs and to close not stansdard ports like 1234 to just 443

any suggestions

Thanks in advance

I am currently use EIP for each server,
I expect to get a solution to help me reduce number of IPs and increase security by close non standard potts

Comment: not entirely clear what you are trying to do, but on one single machine, if a port is in use, it is in use.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have multiple processes on a single server listening to the same port. You have to run each Java app on a different port, and configure a separate IP tables rule for each Elastic IP to forward to a different internal port.

---

> and I need to open the port 1234 on firewalls from outside to make the application reachable

No you don't. The only port you need to open in the firewalls is port `443`. That is the port that is used to communicate to the server. Internally, on the actual server, the `iptables` service will forward traffic incoming on port `442` to the appropriate Java service port. That's the entire purpose of using `iptables` for this.

---

> I am searching for an optimal solution to reduce number of reserved IPs and to close not stansdard ports like 1234 to just 443

If each Java app runs at a different path, like `/app1`, `/app2`, etc, then you could use path-based routing via something like an Nginx proxy in front of the Java processes. Or if they are each mapped to a different domain name, you could do the same thing with domain based routing. If neither of those will work for you then you may be stuck with the multiple EIP routing solution that you currently have.

As for "close not standard ports like 1234" you never needed to open those in the first place, since your traffic comes in on port `443` already, and `iptables` was handling that port mapping entirely internally to the server.